# Access 2013: Is it possible to color single lines in Datasheet or Listview?

Tags: ms-access

I've searched now for hours but only found "conditional formatting". This conditional formatting seems not to work in Form, Subform or Listview, just in a report I managed that.

I want something VERY simple: Just color specific rows in a list on a form. This can't be difficult... but somehow it is.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Conditional formatting most certainly works with continuous forms. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: thanks, managed to create a "fake" table with a conditional field in the background. Not my favorite solution, but it works.